# Fastest way to run two tasks asynchronously and wait until they end

Tags: c#, silverlight

Okay I need to change this..

```
void foo()
{
    DoSomething(1, 0);
    DoSomething(2, 3);
}
```

to something like this...

```
void foo()
{
    //this functions is sync.. I need to run them async somehow
    new Thread(DoSomething(1, 0));
    new Thread(DoSomething(2, 3));

    //Now I need to wait until both async functions will end
    WaitUntilBothFunctionsWillEnd();
}
```

Is there a way to do this in Silverlight?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
void foo()
{
    var thread1 = new Thread(() => DoSomething(1, 0));
    var thread2 = new Thread(() => DoSomething(2, 3));

    thread1.Start();
    thread2.Start();

    thread1.Join();
    thread2.Join();
}
```

The method `Thread.Join()` will block execution until the thread terminates, so joining both threads will ensure that `foo()` will return only after both threads have terminated.

Comment: and what if i need to give some paramethers to those functuions.. for example DoSomething(param1, param2); DoSomething(param1, param2); so both objects param1 and param2 are nesessary for both function calls...

Comment: @Ai_boy: Just substitute in the real parameters: `var thread1 = new Thread(() => DoSomething(param1, param2));`

Comment: @Ai_boy: Are you attempting to tweak the UI on those threads?  All accesses to the UI must be performed on the UI thread to avoid state corruption; the exception is a protective measure here.  Try debugging it and seeing where the exception is thrown.

Comment: I try to pass WritebleBitmap and one Point object.. Both params are same for both functions..

Comment: @Ai_boy: But what do those functions *do?*  Do they modify the UI?

Comment: @Ai_boy: If all they do is modify the UI, then this is not a good approach -- you cannot access the Silverlight UI from anything but the main thread (the one `foo()` will run on).  If the method calculates something that takes a while and *then* modifies the UI, then you could have those calls return the computed value and then modify the UI after the `Join()` calls.

Answer (score 7):

```
Task task1 = Task.Factory.StartNew( () => {DoSomething(1,0);});
Task task2 = Task.Factory.StartNew( () => {DoSomething(2,3);});
Task.WaitAll(task1,task2);
```

You'll need to add the [Microsoft Async](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async/) package (and it's dependents) to your silverlight project.

Comment: While nifty, note that Task is only supported in .NET 4.

Comment: and what if i need to give some paramethers to those functuions.. for example DoSomething(param1, param2); DoSomething(param1, param2); so both objects param1 and param2 are nesessary for both function calls?

Comment: Not only is it not supported previous to .NET 4, but it is also not supported in any version of Silverlight as the OP requested.

Comment: @ai_boy you can pass anything you care to into your DoSomething function (you question offered the literals 1,0,2,3)  Remember however that you'll have two different threads mucking with the same memory at the same time, so your DoSomething will likely have to use a lock block which may defeat the whole purpose.

Comment: BTW: didn't find it in SL.. is Task class avalible in Async CTP?

Answer (score 3):

Even though the [TPL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx) like Ralph's answer suggested is not available in Silverlight, I really like the Task model... So why not write a thin thread-wrapper that would work similarly.

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Linq;

public class Task {
    ManualResetEvent _mre = new ManualResetEvent(false);

    public Task(Action action) {
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((s) => {
            action();
            _mre.Set();
        });
    }

    public static void WaitAll(params Task[] tasks) {
        WaitHandle.WaitAll(tasks.Select(t => t._mre).ToArray());
    }
}
```

Then you could use this a lot like the TPL:

```
int param1 = 1;
int param2 = 2;
Task.WaitAll(
    new Task( () => DoSomething(param1, param2) ),
    new Task( () => DoSomething(param1, param2) )
);
```

Under the covers this puts the responsibility on the ThreadPool of limiting the threads in the system to a reasonable count.

Comment: The use of the ThreadPool to manage the creation and starting of the Tasks, and the use of Linq to harvest out the ManualResetEvents as an array to waiton is a nice bit of concise coding.