# How Run Multiple UI Actions Asyncronously in Silverlight?

Tags: c#, multithreading, silverlight, asynchronous, async-await

### What I have seen

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4402109/fastest-way-to-run-two-tasks-asynchronously-and-wait-until-they-end) shows how asynchronously run multiple tasks and wait for all of them. Here is the solution:

```
var thread1 = new Thread(() => DoSomething(1, 0));
var thread2 = new Thread(() => DoSomething(2, 3));

thread1.Start();
thread2.Start();

thread1.Join();
thread2.Join();
```

### The problem

But it seems those task are non-UI task. I have the same problem but with UI task. If you want do UI-related task in WPF/Silverlight you should use `Dispatcher`, So I tried this code:

```
Thread GetThread(Action action)
{
    return new Thread(()=>
    {
        Application.Current.RootVisual.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(()=>
        {
            action();
        });
    });
}
```

And this how I use it:

```
var thread1=GetThread(async ()=>{UIProperty1 = await GetUIPropertyValuesFromWebServiceAsync1();});
var thread2=GetThread(async ()=>{UIProperty2 = await GetUIPropertyValuesFromWebServiceAsync2();});

thread1.Start();
thread2.Start();
```

But it throws this exception

> Invalid cross-thread access.

How to correct this code to run multiple UI-related task asynchronously? Also I'm looking for best-practices.

### **EDIT #1: Why I'm using threads**

If I use this approach:

```
UIProperty1 = await GetUIPropertyValuesFromWebServiceAsync1(); // Call some web service
UIProperty2 = await GetUIPropertyValuesFromWebServiceAsync2(); // Call some web service
```

These methods will be called one after another and I prefer to call them at the same time (there are more than two web service calls)

### EDIT #2: Why I don't use TaskEx.WhenAll approach

```
var task1 = GetUIPropertyValuesFromWebServiceAsync1(); // Call some web service
var task2 = GetUIPropertyValuesFromWebServiceAsync2(); // Call some web service

TaskEx.WhenAll(task1, task2); // it seems this line never finishes!

UIProperty1 = task1.Result; //never reaches this line
UIProperty2 = task2.Result;
```

Comment: What are those tasks going to do? Do they actually have an asynchronous operation to invoke, or do you only want to update a UI element? If it's the latter, why use tasks or threads at all?

Comment: Yes they do. There are some methods like `GetUIProperty1`   which are async methods and I want to set their result to some properties. (Actually those methods calls some webservices methods)

Comment: Then why do you need threads at all? why not simply invoke them in some event handler and `await` on them?

Comment: They return `Task<List<T>>` and if I use `await` keyword the will be called one after another. Also I tried calling them and used `TaskEx.WhenAll` but with no success.

Comment: You want to call those tasks concurrently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need for threads, especially if you need to operate on UI elements.
If you prefer to call both methods at the same time, you can use `TaskEx.WhenAll` from [`Microsoft.Bcl.Async`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async/):

```
public async void SomeEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var firstUiProperty = GetUIProperty1Async();
    var secondUiProperty = GetUIProperty2Async();
    await TaskEx.WhenAll(firstUiProperty, secondUiProperty);
}
```

Comment: We don't have `Task.WhenAll` in silverlight.

Comment: I want to call multiple web services asynchronously and then set their results to some property of the UI. So I'm interested to know the inside of your e.g. `GetUIProperty1Async()` method.

Comment: It is the same as your `GetUIProperty1` method. You simply need to return the thing you want to set from your method.

Comment: You need to also add your `GetUIPropertyValuesFromWebServiceAsync1` and `GetUIPropertyValuesFromWebServiceAsync2` methods. Also, you're not using `await` on `TaskEx.WhenAll`.

Comment: Yes using `await` before the `TaskEx` was the point. But there is no need to add those methods since I've already added them

Comment: This line `TaskEx.WhenAll(task1, task2);`

Comment: @HosseinNarimaniRad Huh? I want the implementation of those methods. What does that have to do with `WhenAll`? You say it never passes `WhenAll`, I'm assuming you have a deadlock somewhere.

Comment: Using `await` before the `TaskEx` solves the problem. Maybe I miss to mention those methods returns `Task<SomeType>` (actually they are some wrappers which call some web service methods)

Comment: @HosseinNarimaniRad The deadlock you were seeing is probably due to the fact that you weren't using `await` on `TaskEx.WhenAll`, and then you were blocking with `task1.Result`, which caused the code to deadlock.